How to make Tikz-cd diagram symmetric
I'm drawing a young lattice in tikz-cd, trying to copy this image:

My current code is this:
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage[aligntableaux = center, smalltableaux = true]{ytableau}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzcd}[every arrow/.append style={dash}]
  \ydiagram{4} \ar[rd] && \ydiagram{3,1}\ar[ld]\ar[rd] & \ydiagram{2, 2}\ar[d] & \ydiagram{2, 1, 1}\ar[ld]\ar[rd] && \ydiagram{1, 1, 1, 1}\ar[ld]\\
                &\ydiagram{3}\ar[rd] && \ydiagram{2, 1}\ar[ld]\ar[rd] && \ydiagram{1, 1, 1}\ar[ld]\\
                &&\ydiagram{2}\ar[rd]&&\ydiagram{1, 1}\ar[ld]\\
                &&&\ydiagram{1}\ar[d]\\
                &&& \varnothing
\end{tikzcd}

\end{document}


Unfortunately, the output looks a lot worse than the diagram below as it is highly asymmetric. Is there anyway to add padding around the young diagrams so that the entire diagram is symmetric like the one I'm trying to copy? Additionally, in the original diagram the arrow lengths are all different, which helps to create the symmetry? Is it possible to do this with tikz-cd? Finally, is it possible to make the diagram less wide?　
The below is what my diagram looks like:


Adapting the solution here: tikz-cd: draw commutative square as an actual square
We can set fixed row and column sep parameters to make the diagram more symmetrical.
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{ytableau}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzcd}[every arrow/.append style={dash},column sep={3cm,between origins},row sep={3cm,between origins}]
  \ydiagram{4} \ar[rd] && \ydiagram{3,1}\ar[ld]\ar[rd] & \ydiagram{2, 2}\ar[d] & \ydiagram{2, 1, 1}\ar[ld]\ar[rd] && \ydiagram{1, 1, 1, 1}\ar[ld]\\
                &\ydiagram{3}\ar[rd] && \ydiagram{2, 1}\ar[ld]\ar[rd] && \ydiagram{1, 1, 1}\ar[ld]\\
                &&\ydiagram{2}\ar[rd]&&\ydiagram{1, 1}\ar[ld]\\
                &&&\ydiagram{1}\ar[d]\\
                &&& \varnothing
\end{tikzcd}

\end{document}


